# How can I securely allow everyone to read and auth users to write to application with Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am building a social media application in which anyone can read what is going on but have to sign in to interact with each post. I would like to find a way to allow all my users to be able to do this without having an insecure database. I am almost done with development and I am currently trying to clean up a few things.

My current Rules are set to true for development purposes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I have tried a few rules

1.

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
  }
}
```

Which allows everyone to read but doesn't allow writing due to permissions.

2)

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
  }
}
```

Which doesn't allow anyone to read or write due to permissions.

3.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

Which works but I get an email later telling me my database is insecure.

Here is an example that causes a permission denied error:

A) When the user clicks the send new announcement button
This func is called.

```
 StorageService.sendAnnouncementDataToDatabase(photoUrl: "", announcementComment: announcementComment, ratio: CGFloat(0), onSuccess: {
ProgressHUD.showSuccess("SWEET")
})
```

B) Inside sendAnnouncementDataToDatabase func

```
        let ref = Ref().databaseAnnouncements
        let newAnnouncementID = ref.childByAutoId().key ?? ""
        let newAnnouncementReference = ref.child(newAnnouncementID)
        guard let currentUser = Api.User.CURRENT_USER  else {
            return
        }
  
        var dict = ["userId" : currentUserId, "photoUrl" : photoUrl]
        
        newAnnouncementReference.setValue(dict, withCompletionBlock: {(error,ref) in
// permission denied occurs here
})
```

I have read through many documents, and stack question. As well as tried to set rules for each path. Same outcome.

Any ideas would be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Your security rules should allow the data access that your code needs, but deny any other data access. These rules are quite generic, so will allow/deny generically. If you want to secure for data access patterns of your app, show the code for an operation that should be allowed, and for an operation that should be denied.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand what you are saying. When a user is in-app there is really nowhere for them to see anyone else data. Still, I was hoping there was a generic way to simply allow the right access for everyone. I will update my post

Comment: Your code doesn't match the rules in #2, which are the most secure of what you shared. If you want to control access to a specific user, you need to use that user's UID in the path to that data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think I understand what you are saying. That table is simply called announcements. So I would have to have announcements in my path then the specific uid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the *actual* goal

> in which anyone can read what is going on but have to sign in to
> interact with each post

then this rule will do it

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

As it allows anyone to read anything, but only authenticated users can write.

However, it's pretty insecure as Frank mentioned in his comments. We may be able to expand on this solution a bit but without understanding the entire use case it could go well beyond what can be posted here as a full answer.

Comment: I've actually tried this as well. It was on the basic rules firebase documentation. I still got the same insecure issue in my mail. The use case is simply allowing users to post to a newsfeed, comment on other's posts, and inform the entirety of the newsfeed. So I thought the solution you provided was enough. It's just not secure

Comment: @XavierJamesShelton This is the solution to the question. However, you will continue to get the insecure email message as anyone can read ALL of the data in your entire database - which may or may be an issue but anyone that creates and account and/or authenticates can also WRITE any data. That means any one user could for example, spoof another user and post a fake message. Not sure if that matters in your use case but it may.

Comment: Well, I think this did help I believe that the last comment you said is what I really needed to understand. I have a lot of in-app security so honestly, as long as no one can basically break into my DB from being able to read everything I am fine. Thank you.